# Return Type Format of Python pygame.midi.Input.read()

Tags: python, pygame, midi, piano

I've searched a lot to find out what does the `pygame.midi.Input.read()` returns.

In every documentation I found they say it's

```
[[status,data1,data2,data3],timestamp],...]
```

But what the hell is **data1, data2, data3**?

Someone, please explain what each list item's type and use in relation to MIDI data

Comment: The official documentation I found https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html#pygame.midi.Input.read

Comment: The status and data bytes are specified in the [MIDI specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications/midi1-specifications/m1-v4-2-1-midi-1-0-detailed-specification-96-1-4).

Answer (score 0):

The status and data bytes are specified in the [MIDI specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications/midi1-specifications/m1-v4-2-1-midi-1-0-detailed-specification-96-1-4). A short summery can also be found at [Music - Midi - Status and Data Bytes](https://www.euclideanspace.com/art/music/midi/codes/index.htm).
In the Pygame documentation of [`pygame.midi.read`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html#pygame.midi.Input.read) the data structure of the return value is defined:

> **Returns**: the format for midi_event_list is `[[[status, data1, data2, data3], timestamp], ...]`

Pygame uses the [PortMidi (Platform Independent Library for MIDI I/O)](https://portmedia.sourceforge.net/portmidi/), where further documentation can be found.

There is also an example in the Pygame repository how to use the midi module: [pygame/examples/midi.py](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/main/examples/midi.py#L29)

And there are some other StackOverflow questions related to this topic:

- [Playing midi on Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913047/playing-midi-on-pygame)
- [Pygame read MIDI input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64818410/pygame-read-midi-input)
- [Playing note with pygame.midi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863534/playing-note-with-pygame-midi)